# Filter on custom field across multiple models that import from Wagtail core Page

Tags: django, wagtail

I have two custom `Page` models that share a field in common, for example:

```py
class CustomPageModelOne(Page):
    custom_field = models.IntegerField()
    ...

class CustomPageModelTwo(Page):
    custom_field = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

I need to run, ideally, a single filter across the two types of custom `Page` models. The Wagtail docs say I can use an `exact_type` method to specify multiple models inheriting from core `Page`, so I am trying some variations of the following:

```py
Page.objects.exact_type(CustomPageModelOne, CustomPageModelTwo).filter(custom_field=123)
```

However, when I try to filter any QuerySet that uses both models, I get an error:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'custom_field' into field.

How can I query across multiple Wagtail custom Page models that share a field in common?

Note: I have considered creating an abstract class inheriting from `Page`, but cannot import that abstract model in the file where it is needed.

Abstract class example:

```py
class CustomFieldModel(Page):
    custom_field = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class CustomPageModelOne(CustomFieldModel):
    pass

class CustomPageModelTwo(CustomFieldModel):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do `Page.objects...` you can only filter on [fields of the Page model](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.13/reference/pages/model_reference.html#database-fields) and subclasses of `Page`

To filter specifically on fields of your `CustomPageModelOne`, you would have to use `CustomPageModel.objects...` where that model has that field and both your custom page models are subclasses from

Comment: Can I use an abstract model? I.e. I don't need an empty table for the parent model. If it's possible to use an abstract model as a base, what might be the issue when I try to import the abstract model?

Comment: @BrylieChristopherOxley you can not do queries on abstract models. Therefore, an abstract model as a base would not work.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `Page.objects.exact_type` is only returning a queryset based upon `Page`, which makes sense because `exact_type` has no way of knowing what fields would occur on models descended from `Page`.  I would suggest the following as an alternative approach if re-architecting your models is not an option:

```
from itertools import chain

model_one_results = CustomPageModelOne.objects.filter(custom_field=123)
model_two_results = CustomPageModelTwo.objects.filter(custom_field=123)
all_results = list(chain(model_one_results, model_two_results))
```